# the trait `std::marker::Sync` is not implemented for `std::sync::mpsc::Sender<i32>

Tags: rust, async-await, concurrency, rust-tokio

I'm attempting to build a multithreaded application using MPSC and I'm running into the error in the title. I'm not sure what the proper pattern for this use case is - I'm looking for a pattern that will allow me to clone the producer channel and move it into a new thread to be used.

This new thread will keep an open websocket and send a subset of the websocket message data through the producer whenever a websocket message is received. Data from other threads will be needed in the consumer thread which is why I assume the MPSC pattern is a suitable choice.

In addition to the message in the title it also shows these:

```
`std::sync::mpsc::Sender<i32>` cannot be shared between threads safely
help: the trait `std::marker::Sync` is not implemented for `std::sync::mpsc::Sender`
```

Can/should I implement `Send` for this? Is this an appropriate time to use `Rc` or `Pin`? I believe this is happening because I'm attempting to send a type that doesn't implement `Send` across an `.await` in an `async` closure, but I don't what to make of it or what to reach for in this situation.

I've been able to reduce my issue down to this:

```
use futures::stream::{self, StreamExt};
use std::sync::mpsc::{channel, Receiver, Sender};

#[tokio::main]
async fn main() {
    let (tx, rx): (Sender<i32>, Receiver<i32>) = channel();

    tokio::spawn(async move {
        let a = [1, 2, 3];
        let mut s = stream::iter(a.iter())
            .cycle()
            .for_each(move |int| async {
                tx.send(*int);
            })
            .await;
    });
}
```

Comment: You need to clone the sender for each thread you give it to. But beyond that, you probably don't want to use `std::sync::mpsc` channels in this case since they will block the thread. Instead you likely want to look into the channels `tokio` provides that support async/await.

Comment: Using the  `async` channels from the `tokio` library is indeed the solution I was looking for. Thank you @Locke!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are several issues with your code. The first is that you're missing a `move` in the innermost `async` block, so the compiler tries to borrow a reference to `tx`. That's why you get the error that `Sender` (type of `tx`) doesn't implement `Sync`.

Once you add the missing `move` you get a different error:

```
error[E0507]: cannot move out of `tx`, a captured variable in an `FnMut` closure
```

Now the issue is that `for_each()` will call the closure multiple times, so you are actually not allowed to move `tx` into the async block - because there would be nothing *to* move after the first invocation of the closure.

Since MPSC channels allow multiple producers, `Sender` implements `Clone`, so you can simply clone `tx` before moving it to the async block. This compiles:

```
let (tx, _rx): (Sender<i32>, Receiver<i32>) = channel();

tokio::spawn(async move {
    let a = [1, 2, 3];
    let _s = stream::iter(a.iter())
        .cycle()
        .for_each(move |int| {
            let tx = tx.clone();
            async move {
                tx.send(*int).unwrap();
            }
        })
        .await;
});
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=d7d34c43756a9cd5e9ee7497646a17a8)

Finally, as pointed out in the comments, you almost certainly want to use async channels here. While the channel you create is unbounded, so senders will never block, the receiver *will* block when there are no messages and therefore halt a whole executor thread.

As it happens, the sender side of tokio MPSC channels also implements `Sync`, allowing code close to the one in your question to compile:

```
let (tx, mut rx) = tokio::sync::mpsc::unbounded_channel();

tokio::spawn(async move {
    let a = [1, 2, 3];
    let _s = stream::iter(a.iter())
        .cycle()
        .for_each(|int| async {
            tx.send(*int).unwrap();
        })
        .await;
});

assert_eq!(rx.recv().await, Some(1));
assert_eq!(rx.recv().await, Some(2));
assert_eq!(rx.recv().await, Some(3));
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=1e6f2b2df2af0fe7321fe203af483758)

Comment: This response doesn't just answer my question correctly; it provides enough context to help me understand a number of points about asynchronous programming in Rust that I wasn't able to grasp from the docs. 
The part about how a synchronous receiver would block even for an unbounded channel was particularly helpful in understanding how the sync and async patterns relate.
Thank you; I appreciate you taking the time to explain this in a plain and thorough way.